# Removing libsqlite3-0 deletes Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, svn, sqlite, apt

I have Ubuntu 13.04 in a Virtualbox, and getting

```
SQLite header and source version mismatch
```

In fact, for completeness, it's part of a wider problem with SVN, where `svn update` responds with

```
E200029: Couldn't perform atomic initialization svn
E200030: SQLite compiled for 3.7.15.2, but running with 3.6.23
```

I followed [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1883976):

```
$apt-get purge libsqlite3-0
```

and got

```
After this operation, 994 MB disk space will be freed.
```

As I had taken a backup of my VM I said Yes, and it deleted almost all of Ubuntu (before then restoring the backup!).  Is this a know bug? Or another issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably "working as intended":

SQLite is a very common technology, and there are many, many programs which depend upon it. If you purge it from your system, then all the programs which require it will also be removed. I.e., if SVN requires SQLite and you remove SQLite, then SVN will *also* be removed. You need to install another version of or package which provides `libsqlite3-0` before or at the same time as you remove `libsqlite3-0 v3.6.23` to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Ah, ok - that makes sense.

Comment: Although, after 3 hours, I still can't sort out my `SQLite header and source version mismatch` issue...

Comment: @ChrisW did you build `svn` from source? SVN was compiled with version 3.7.15.2 of the SQLite development headers (the `-dev` package), but you only have version 3.6.23 of the actual library installed on your system. You should rebuild against version 3.6.23 of the development headers, or install version 3.7.15.2 on your system.

Comment: I didn't compile SVN from source. Whatever I do with uninstalling and resintalling SQLite (using apt-get and compiling from source) I can't get rid of the issue... I can't even *find* the SQLite dev package

Comment: (for completion, I've made a new question based on the overarching issue: http://superuser.com/questions/631088/ubuntu-sqlite-header-source-mismatch