# Ubuntu: SQLite header / source mismatch (and making SVN use the installed SQLite installation)

Tags: ubuntu, sqlite

I have the annoying `SQLite header and source version mismatch` problem when trying to run SQLite3 on Ubuntu 13.04. I've done in various orders (and all multiple times):

- `apt-get remove sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev`, and reinstallation
- `ldconfig`
- Compiled sqlite from source using the  `autoconf` tar.gz
- Tried everything I've found on Google...

Yet I can't figure out what's wrong. I've wasted 3 hours of my life on this!

And in fact, why does the following happen:

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite header and source version mismatch
2010-03-09 19:31:43 4ae453ea7be69018d8c16eb8dabe05617397dc4d
2013-05-20 00:56:22 118a3b35693b134d56ebd780123b7fd6f1497668
$ apt-get remove sqlite3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'sqlite3' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

If `sqlite3` isn't installed, how can it think there's a mismatch?!

**Update**

Right, thanks to Aaron, I've now got as far as

```
$ locate libsqlite3.so
/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so
/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```

I've moved them to a temp dir, and now get

```
$ sqlite3
The program 'sqlite3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

I did

```
$ apt-get install sqlite3
$ apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

And **STILL** get the same mismatch error

And I've removed the spurious `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3ext.h` files that were still around, repeated everything, and still get the issues...

Comment: If `sqlite3` wasn't installed, invoking it on the command line would fail. Presumably there's a copy still installed somewhere, perhaps left over from your manual installation attempt; remove that, confirm that `updatedb; locate libsqlite3.so` doesn't find anything except in your build directories, then reinstall via `apt-get`.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned the header files as well; see if you've got `libsqlite3.h` hanging around somewhere, and likewise move them to a temporary directory. (It may be that `apt` won't overwrite those files when installing `libsqlite3-dev`.)

Comment: Yeh, I've done that too and still get the issue :/

Comment: I wish I knew what else to suggest.

Comment: I've hacked my round it and posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More background: I was trying to install SQLite3 because when I ran any SVN command, I got an error:

```
E200029: Couldn't perform atomic initialization 
E200030: SQLite compiled for 3.7.15.2, but running with 3.6.23
```

I assumed that fixing my install of SQLite would fix that. However, I *think* the main issue is that Ubuntu 13.04 **requires** SQLite 3.6.23, and that is the reason why running

```
apt-get purge libsqlite3-0
```

deletes most of Ubuntu (see [this related answer](https://superuser.com/a/631048/142069) for further details).

After lots of headbanging, shouting, and crying, I decided to try to install SVN from source (as opposed to SQLite, which is what I said I'd done in my question).  This was actually relatively straightforward, albeit a little time-consuming.

Basically:

```
wget http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/rsync.apache.org/subversion/subversion-1.8.1.tar.bz2
tar xjvf subversion-1.8.1.tar.bz2
```

I then found out I needed the APR and APR-utils libraries, so:

```
wget http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/rsync.apache.org/apr/apr-1.4.8.tar.bz2
wget http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/rsync.apache.org/apr/apr-util-1.5.2.tar.bz2

tar xjvf apr-1.4.8.tar.bz2
cd apr-1.4.8
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..
tar xjvf apr-util-1.5.2.tar.bz2
cd apr-util-1.5.2
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr
make
sudo make install
```

...and the serf library (I didn't compile with this the 1st time, but this provides http support - without it SVN can only handle `file` and `svn` protocols)..:

```
wget https://serf.googlecode.com/files/serf-1.3.0.tar.bz2
tar xjvf serf-1.3.0.tar.bz2
scons APR=/usr/local/apr APU=/usr/local/apr
sudo scons install
scons -c
```

These are the same commands as in the [serf README](http://code.google.com/p/serf/source/browse/trunk/README) (if scons isn't installed it's available via `apt-get`).

SVN also wants the SQLite amalgamation .c file, so [download the amalagation](http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) and untar it for now - I created a `~/sqlite-amalgamation` folder and left everything here.  You should then be ready to compile svn.  Serf should have installed to a standard place, so doesn't need a location specified

```
sudo ./configure --with-sqlite=/home/chris/sqlite-amalgamation/sqlite3.c --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr --with-serf
make
sudo make install
```

and hopefully that's it.  I had SVN error of

```
The working copy needs to be upgraded
```

but when I tried `svn upgrade` I got a SVN database error... the only way round it was to checkout a new version into a new location. But, SVN now works!

It doesn't fix the underlying SQLite3 issue, and I still get the same header / source version mismatch error when doing `$ sqlite3`, but since I don't need to use standalone SQLite at the moment, that problem can wait until another day (or, is it infact something that should be registered as a bug with Ubuntu?)

Comment: Glad to know you found your way around it! I'll admit, I've been leery of the "build it yourself" distros like Slackware and Gentoo, but between this and the travails I've endured in my (ultimately successful) effort to set up a Linux VM to host Emacs on my Windows machine at home, I'm strongly tempted to give them another look with fresh eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I just replaced older version of SQlite library @ location

```
"/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6"
```

with newer version which is @ location

```
"/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6"
```

Now latest sqlite version

```
$ sqlite3 --version 
3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30 27392118af4c38c5203a04b8013e1afdb1cebd0d
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I still get 'version mismatch'

Answer (score 1):

This solved my case, linux comes with an older version of sqlite this is why its bringing this problem, do this to sort it out.

1. mv /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6  /usr/lib/i386-linuxgnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6_bak
2. mv /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0_bak

   And then copy the database was compiled in Autoconf packets in the past:

   1. cd /usr/local/lib

   2. cp libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu

   3. cp libsqlite3.so.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu

This problem was solved. you will need to run with sudo.